# android sqlite check if inserted new value

Tags: android, database, sqlite, t-sql

I'm working with sqlite. I successfully created database and table. I also wrote code which can insert new values in my table. My code is working perfect, but now I want to show for example: toast message if inserted new value, else show error message in toast or something  else. 
This is a my insert to table source code:

```
public void InsertToPhysicalPersonTable(String FirstName, String LastName,
        String FullName, String FatherName) {
    try {
        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
        newValues.put("FirstName", FirstName);
        newValues.put("LastName", LastName);
        newValues.put("FullName", FullName);
        newValues.put("FatherName", FatherName);



        db.insert(AddNewPhysicalPerson, null, newValues);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(myContext, "Something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

I called my function like this:

```
loginDataBaseAdapter.InsertToPhysicalPersonTable("FirstName",
                    "LastName",
                    "FullName",
                    "FatherName"
                    );
```

If anyone knows the solution, please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`insert()` method returns the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred.

Change

```
db.insert(AddNewPhysicalPerson, null, newValues);
```

like this

```
long rowInserted = db.insert(AddNewPhysicalPerson, null, newValues);
if(rowInserted != -1)
    Toast.makeText(myContext, "New row added, row id: " + rowInserted, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else
    Toast.makeText(myContext, "Something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Can we use the same for update query, will it return the updated row ID

Answer (score 4):

```
long result = db.insert(table name, null, contentvalues);
      if(result==-1)
          return false;
           else
          return true;
```

this is good solution for it..

Answer (score 0):

here is another way:-

I don't know if I am too late for your project but have you thought of `.lastrowid`?

Here is an example of what I did `last_rec=self.cursor.lastrowid` so `lastrec` would have the number of the last row inserted.

Here is the info from [sqlite.org](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html)

Hope it helps, you , or anyone else who wonders about this.

Kind regards and all the best :¬)

*joe*